# Bolt/Fire Damage stat on weapons

Tags: bloodborne

I've been really confused about this since I started getting my first attribute adding gems.

I am getting gems that add fire/bolt damage to a weapons. Still, adding that gem to a weapon doesn't activate flame/bolt visual effect.

I am wonder if those elemental damages actually work if the appropriate paper is not activated. For instance does a sword with +20 fire damage gem add the fire damage to each hit or does the +20 only increase effect of fire paper?

Also, assuming I use a weapon with fire damage gem, but no fire paper, do oil urns make the fire damage more effective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get a gem that 'adds fire damage', it usually converts all damage done to fire.  Same with bolt.  It does two things: converts all damage from the weapon into elemental damage and converts the scaling of the weapon to Arcane.  This usually significantly reduces the amount of damage you do with the weapon, in favor of scaling off of Arcane and doing elemental damage.  While the effect does not show on your weapon, it does show when you hit someone with it (a fire weapon will show a fire effect when you hit an enemy).

You do not need bolt or fire paper for this.  Paper only adds the effect to the weapon if it wasn't already there.  So, for a normal weapon that you add fire paper for, you simply add a fire damage number to the weapon that, again, scales off of arcane.

And oil does increase the effect of fire damage done to a target, no matter what that damage source is.

To test out your numbers, I suggest getting two weapons, leveling them up evenly, then leveling up your damage stat (either Dex or Str) evenly, then having one of them slot your fire gem.  Watch the numbers change with the new scaling.

Comment: That is a lot of new information, thanks! Also, does that mean a combination of: weapon scaled to 250 damage, a fire gem, an oil urn and beast enemy would result in insane damage?

Comment: I have not found a gem that 'adds' fire scaling or lighting scaling to a weapon.  I have only seen ones that change the scaling.  The most damage I can see getting out of something like this would be using a high normal damage weapon, using oil on the target, and then using fire paper.  I could be wrong, but I don't think any gems 'add' fire scaling.

Comment: Oh, I just meant that if weapon with physical damage maxed out would deal the insane damage under those circumstances. I will test the weapons as soon as I get a chance to play, although, i never noticed that huge jump in damage when using fire paper on beasts Thank you for your help. Some of the game's mechanics really are too hard to figure out on my own!